# Accessing Ubuntu chef server using hostname in my windows machine won't work

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, chef-infra

I am not familiar with setting up and configuring chef server, workstation and nodes. But I was stuck in here. Greatly appreciate any help from experts.

I have an Ubuntu 14.04.2 machine with chef-server 12.0.8-1 installed. Everything is working fine as expected.

And now I was setting up the workstation in my windows VM machine. I installed chef-client 12.2.1-1, chefdk-0.4.0-1. I downloaded the chef-starter kit from my chef server machine (https://ip_address/organizations/some_org). I issue 'knife ssl fetch' command so that the self-signed certificate will be download. When I check the connectivity between my workstation and chef server. I got the following error.

> ERROR: Network Error: getaddrinfo: No such host is known. Check your knife configuration and network settings.

I checked the knife.rb and the the value of chef_server_url is https://hostname/organizations/some_org. I tried changing the hostname into the ip adress and I was able to execute the 'knife ssl fetch command'. But when execute the 'knife ssl check' I got the following error.

> Connecting to host *ipaddress*
>   ERROR: The SSL cert is signed by a trusted authority but is not valid for the given hostname
>   ERROR: You are attempting to connect to:   '*ipaddress*'
>   ERROR: The server's certificate belongs to '*hostname*'

Anything I missed here and anything I need to do?

Thank you.

Comment: Configure your dns properly. Your chef server should have a name as certificates are using the hostname and this name should resolve to your server address.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean on configuring the dns server. Can you broaden it a little bit? Thanks.

Comment: It's really off topic for SO. The message: "getaddrinfo: No such host is known." is clear enough. You're trying to call `titi`, your windows host ask its dns server about it, this dns server has no clue about a `titi` nor a `titi.your.local.domain` and answer with "NX_DOMAIN". Try a `ping hostname` or a `nslookup hostname`, they'll fail too. You have to configure your host with a correct name, or to configure the dns server properly. That's part of system administration in a network.

Comment: @Tensibai Yeah this is part of system administration in a network that I don't know much knowledge.